# Draw a circle on the Canvas of a TImage with Delphi Firemonekey

Tags: delphi, firemonkey

I am trying draw a circle on the TImage canvas in Delphi 11 Firemonkey using the OnMouseDown event of the TImage component.
I have written the following code:

```
procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  // sets the size of the TBitmap
  Image1.Bitmap.SetSize(Round(Image1.Width), Round(Image1.Height));
  Image1.Bitmap.Clear(TAlphaColors.White);
end;


procedure TForm1.Image1MouseDown(Sender: TObject; Button: TMouseButton; Shift: TShiftState; X, Y: Single);
var
  MyRect: TRectF;
  Point:TPointF;
begin
   // sets the circumscribed rectangle of the ellipse
  Caption:=X.ToString +',' +Y.ToString;
  Point:=TPointF.Create(x,y);
  //Point:=ClientToScreen(Point);
  Point:=Image1.AbsoluteToLocal(Point);
  MyRect := TRectF.Create(Point,5,5);

  // draws the ellipse on the canvas
  Image1.Bitmap.Canvas.BeginScene;
  Image1.Bitmap.Canvas.DrawEllipse(MyRect, 20);
  Image1.Bitmap.Canvas.EndScene;
end;
```

When I run the app and click on the Timage, the circle is drawn as expected, but not at the exact position, it has an offset away from the mouse pointer.
How can I correct this displacement?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

The X,Y coordinates provided by the `OnMouseDown` event are expressed as local coordinates relative to the `TImage`'s client area, they are not expressed as global absolute coordinates.  So, you should not be trying to convert `Point` from absolute coordinates to local coordinates at all, it is already in local coordinates.

You need to remove the call to `Image1.AbsoluteToLocal()` and just use the coordinates provided as-is, eg:

```pascal
procedure TForm1.Image1MouseDown(Sender: TObject;
  Button: TMouseButton; Shift: TShiftState; X, Y: Single);
var
  MyRect: TRectF;
  Point: TPointF;
begin
   // sets the circumscribed rectangle of the ellipse
  Caption := X.ToString + ',' + Y.ToString;
  Point := TPointF.Create(X, Y);
  MyRect := TRectF.Create(Point, 5, 5);

  // draws the ellipse on the canvas
  Image1.Bitmap.Canvas.BeginScene;
  Image1.Bitmap.Canvas.DrawEllipse(MyRect, 20);
  Image1.Bitmap.Canvas.EndScene;
end;
```

Comment: I've added   point:=Image1.AbsoluteToLocal(Point); below to  Point:=TPointF.Create(x,y) line, but not work :(

Comment: "*I've added ... but not work*" - I know, which is why I told you to GET RID of that call, you should not be using it in this situation to begin with.

Comment: Sorry for the misunderstanding, but I have also tried it and it still continues with a displacement to the right of the mouse pointer.
I have noticed that the Tbitmap canvas contains a margin that separates it from the left and rigth  of the Timage causing the error. I have modified the Image1.BitmapMargins property to 0 but not work still.

Comment: @PedroLuque it is difficult to see that, when everything in your screenshot is using the same color.  Can you please change the colors so the TForm's title and client area, the TImage, and the TBitmap, are using different colors? Thanks.

Comment: I found the problem, by default the wrapMode property of the TImage is  seted as fit , I've changed to Original then it work!